# Number of rationals with denominator less than $N$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, asymptotics

This is probably a duplicate since it seems like elementary number theory, but didn't find it after a cursory search. Let $r(N)$ be the number of rationals in $[0,1]$ with denominator less than or equal to $N$. Is there an asymptotic expression for $r(N)$?

A cute Mathematica script shows the following:

```
r[m_] := Union[Flatten@Table[k/j, {j, m}, {k, 0, j}]];
ListLinePlot[Table[Length[r[k]]/k^2, {k, 150}], PlotRange -> {0, 0.5}]
```

[image]

and `Length[r[2000]]/2000.0^2` gives 0.304147. If $r(N)$ has a quadratic asymptotic expression, what is its coefficient?

Comment: If one writes rationals as $\frac{p}{q}$, where $1\leq p < q$ are positive integers, then there are $\varphi(q)$ rationals with denominator $q$ in the interval $[0,1]$. Here $\varphi)$ is Euler's totient function. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function

Comment: @Mathmo123: Yes. For example, `r[2]` gives `{0, 1/2, 1}`.

Comment: @JankoBracic: Nice. From that we obtain the result $$r(N)=\sum_{n=-1}^N\varphi(n)\sim\frac{3}{\pi^2}N^2.$$

Comment: I guess that you are right. I should say before that it is assumed that $gcd(p,q)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

As Janko pointed out, we have
$$r(N)=\sum_{n=-1}^N\varphi(n)\sim\frac{3}{\pi^2}N^2$$
so the coefficient of growth is $3/\pi^2=0.3039635509\ldots$